# Swapping list of fragments inside FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, fragment, xamarin

I'm having trouble swapping a list of fragments inside my FragmentStatePagerAdapter, and was wondering if anyone might have an idea. I was hoping to have the following feature;

- main activity includes three tabs (restaurants, reviews, favorites), each containing a fragment with a list of restaurants
- user can swipe between each tab to view a different list
- main activity layout has a button. when user presses the button it will swap all the existing fragments with another list of fragments. The new list of fragments will be three fragments with restaurant location maps (google maps) instead of list of restaurants

I currently have the swipe tabs working with actionbar and view pager. I have some degree of success swapping out the list fragments with the map fragments, but the following problem occurs:

- when I hit the button on the main page, the first (restaurants) tab becomes blank.
- when I swipe to the next tab (reviews), the tab is populated with a map fragment
- when I swipe to the third tab (favorites), the tab is empty again

My setting is the following:

- Main activity extending FragmentActivity and implementing ActionBar.ITabListener
- One RestaurantListFragment class is used for the restaurant list fragments, populated with different data for Search, Reviews, and Favorites
- One RestaurantListMap class is used for the map list fragments, again populated with different data for each tab
- One TabPagerAdapter class extending FragmentStatePagerAdapter

I've tried almost every post on stackoverflow about this topic, but so far with no success. Would anyone have any ideas? Code is attached below. Thanks.

```
    //Main activity
    public class Main : FragmentActivity, ActionBar.ITabListener
    {
    //Some generic code here, nothing special
    //....//

    //The button that triggers the fragments swap
        private void BindCommands()
        {
            ListMapSwitchButton.Click += (sender, e) => 
            {
                _isList = !_isList;
                ListMapSwitchButton.Text = _isList ? RESTAURANTS_MAP_TEXT : RESTAURANTS_LIST_TEXT;
                mAdapter.SwapListMapFragments(viewPager);
            };
        }
}


    public class TabsPagerAdapter : FragmentStatePagerAdapter   {

        private void PopulateFragments()
        {
            _fragments = new List<RestaurantFragmentBase> () 
            {
                new RestaurantListFragment (),
                new RestaurantListFragment(),
                new RestaurantListFragment()
            };
        }

        public void SwapListMapFragments(ViewPager pager)
        {

            _fragments.Clear ();
            _fragments.Add (
                new RestaurantMapFragment()
            );
            _fragments.Add (
                new RestaurantMapFragment()
            );
            _fragments.Add (
                new RestaurantMapFragment()
            );

            NotifyDataSetChanged ();
            pager.DestroyDrawingCache ();
        }

        public override int GetItemPosition (Java.Lang.Object itemObject)
        {
            return PositionNone;
        }

        public override Android.App.Fragment GetItem(int index) 
        {
            return _fragments[index];
        }

        #region implemented abstract members of PagerAdapter

        public override int Count {
            get {
                return 3;
            }
        }

        #endregion

    }
```

Note that this code is actually written in C# with Xamarin, but besides syntax differences it should pretty much be the same as Java. Let me know if any additional info might help.